# Ubuntu refuses to shut down but screen is black

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

I run Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a laptop (ASUS ALTEC LANSING).
This morning I wanted to shut down my laptop. The screen is  black now but I noticed it is not shut down at all even if I removed the power supply from it. I kept my finger pushing on the "shut down" button next to its keyboard but it refuses to shut down. 
Now the temperature of my laptop increases and it is Summer here in France. Please what can I do to shut it down ? Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved in the following ways--

1.Get back to any terminal by pressing ctrl+Alt+F1 (or up to F6),then type sudo poweroff

2.Hold down the power button until it shuts down.

3.Remove the battery,wait for some minutes and then insert it and boot.

If none above works ,then, Wait for discharging of the battery and let it cool down,and boot it after charging.

Comment: thank you, but as i explained the screen is totally black, i have no access for ubuntu

Comment: Can you get back in any terminal by pressing ctrl+Alt+F1?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I even press the shutdown key next to the keyboard but it does not respond. The lid is still bright (as if Ubuntu is running). But no sound. The screen is totally black. The laptop is silent.

Comment: Hold down the shutdown button to power it off rather pressing continuously

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will hold it down as long as i can

Comment: do you think after the battery discharges totally in few days it will work normally ?

Comment: Yes,just charge the battery.However,report what happens.

Comment: I kept holding it for 25 minutes but I can not continue. I will wait few hours/days until the battery is discharged totally. Thank you very much for trying to help me

Comment: :\....You can remove the battery,wait for some minutes ,then insert it and boot.

Comment: the battery discharged now. I let it to cold down (to clear the processes from the RAM) and now it workds. You can write the 3 options in your answer and I will accept it because you helped me with your suggestions and we will make this question as answered unlike many others of the same type that have not an answer

Comment: Ok, I am doing it! :)